# Transforming all configs in folder

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

The situation is this:

- I have multiple config files in one folder
- I have transformation files with the same name in a different folder
- I want to output the transformed files with the same name to a third folder after the build

I can easily solve this by manually adding the nodes for each file. However, I don't want to bother with that (as one of us in the team will always forget to edit the csproj file when he/she adds a new config).

This is what I have now:

```xml
<UsingTask 
   TaskName="TransformXml" 
   AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild">

<ItemGroup>
  <PathToConfigs Include="Configurations\EnvironmentDependent" />
  <FilesToTransform Include="*.config"/>
</ItemGroup>

<TransformXml 
    Source="%(PathToConfigs)\%(FilesToTransform)" 
    Destination="OutputConfigs\%(FilesToTransform)" 
    Transform="%(PathToConfigs)\TransformFiles\%(FilesToTransform)" />
```

I don't get the proper syntax here, so it is not suprising that I get the following error message:

*"The item metadata %(PathToConfigs) is being referenced without an item name. Specify the item name by using %(itemname.PathToConfigs)".*

### Update

As of Nick's answer I came to this solution:

```xml
<TransformXml 
    Source="@(FilesToTransform -> '%(Identity)')" 
    Destination="@(FilesToTransform -> '%(OutputFile)')" 
    Transform="@(FilesToTransform -> '%(Transform)')" />
```

I verified the paths of files as shown in the `<Message ... />`-s.

However, I get the following error:

"Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\fakepath\Configurations\EnvironmentDependent\file1.config;Configurations\EnvironmentDependent\file2.config'."

(I have renamed part of the path to C:\fakepath; otherwise I did not change path after the semi-colon: the first path in the error message is absolute, the second one is relative. The output of the message shows the relative paths of the files).

What did go wrong?

### Update 2

Source problem is fixed with `Source="%FilesToTransform.Identity"`. I'm having the same issue with Transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're iterating over the PathToConfigs collection rather than the group of configs.

Use MsBuild properties when referring to a single item, and use MsBuild items when referring to a collection.  Lets first change the path variables to properties rather than items.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PathToConfigs>Configurations\EnvironmentDependent</PathToConfigs>
  <TransformLocation>$(ConfigLocation)\OutputConfigs</TransformLocation>
  <Destination>$(PathToConfigs)\TransformationFiles</Destination>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Next, since we know the transform and output files are based on the structure of the members of the FilesToTransform item group, lets infer those values in the metadata.  First create a group comprising the config files, then construct the FilesToTransform using metadata from the @(Configs) group:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Configs Include="$(PathToConfigs)\*.config" />
  <FilesToTransform Include="@(Configs)">
    <Transform>$(TransformLocation)\%(FileName)%(Extension)</Transform>
    <OutputFile>$(Destination)\%(FileName)%(Extension)</OutputFile>
  </FilesToTransform>
</ItemGroup>
```

Finally, confirm your output in a message task:

```
<Message Importance="High" Text=" Source @(FilesToTransform ->'%(Identity)')" />
<Message Importance="High" Text=" Destination @(FilesToTransform -> '%(OutputFile)')" />
<Message Importance="High" Text=" Transform @(FilesToTransform -> '%(Transform)')" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the neat answer! Actually it took me a lot of debugging until realised that missed to include `Include="@Configs"` from <FilesToTransform>. My bad! :) Thanks again!

Comment: It seemed to me, that I only need to figure out the rest, which would be easy. I have updated my question with the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to figure out the rest after Nick has pointed to the right direction. You have to play with it for the proper syntax:

This is the one that works as intended:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PathToConfigs>Configurations\EnvironmentDependent</PathToConfigs>
  <TransformLocation>Configurations\TransformFilesFor\Environment1</TransformLocation>
  <Destination>$(PathToConfigs)\TransformedConfigs</Destination>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <FilesToTransform Include="$(PathToConfigs)\*.config" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- you can check the path of files here -->

<Message Importance="High" 
     Text=" Source files: %(FilesToTransform.Identity)" />
<Message Importance="High" 
     Text=" Destination files: $(Destination)\%(FilesToTransform.Filename)%(FilesToTransform.Extension)" />
<Message Importance="High" 
     Text=" Transform files: $(TransformLocation)\%(FilesToTransform.Filename)%(FilesToTransform.Extension)" />

<!--
 1>   Source files: Configurations\EnvironmentDependent\config1.config
 1>   Source files: Configurations\EnvironmentDependent\config2.config
 1>   Destination files: Configurations\EnvironmentDependent\TransformedConfigs\config1.config
 1>   Destination files: Configurations\EnvironmentDependent\TransformedConfigs\config2.config
 1>   Transform files: Configurations\TransformFilesFor\Environment1\config1.config
 1>   Transform files: Configurations\TransformFilesFor\Environment1\config2.config
 -->

<TransformXml 
    Source="%(FilesToTransform.Identity)" 
    Destination="$(Destination)\%(FilesToTransform.Filename)%(FilesToTransform.Extension)" 
    Transform="$(TransformLocation)\%(FilesToTransform.Filename)%(FilesToTransform.Extension)" />
```

Any help on a shorter syntax is appreciated, though!

Comment: Take a look at the second and third blocks in my sample.  I intentionally create an intermediary @(Configs) group used to create the @(FilesToTransform) group so that you can reference the metadata in the <TransformXml /> call.

Comment: Yes, I tried that one but didn't work for me. I don't know why, but it just output empty strings. See Update 1 for what I have tried.

Comment: Ah, try this: SourceFiles="@(FilesToTransform)
    Destination="%(FilesToTransform.OutputFile)" 
    Transform="%(FilesToTransform.Transform)" />

Comment: This one leads to "Could not find a part of the path" errors. (On all attributes (Source, Destination, Transform)).